# get current product name in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, production

i create a button in a current product page after woocommerce_single_product_summary

i would to get information about the current product ( for example name and price) and through the button send an email for get information

this is the code of my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','content_after_addtocart_button' );

function content_after_addtocart_button() { 
echo '<div class="content-section">
<a href="mailto:riccardoairone@gmail.com?&subject= Richiesta Informazioni&body= product name ??? product price ??? ">
<input type="button" value="Richiedi Informazioni"/ ></a></div>'; 
}
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','content_after_addtocart_button' );
function content_after_addtocart_button() { 

    global $product;

    $product_title = $product->get_name();
    $product_price = $product->get_price();

    echo '<div class="content-section">
    <a href="mailto:riccardoairone@gmail.com?&subject=Richiesta Informazioni&body=' . $product_title . '??? ' . $product_price . ' ??? ">
    <input type="button" value="Richiedi Informazioni"/ ></a></div>'; 
}
```